# 2 categorical IV and 1 ordinal DV — what test to use?

Tags: experiment-design, multilevel-analysis

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to statistics, and I'm struggling to decide on the design for a statistics test, so I was wondering if someone might be willing and able to help me out please?

Basically, I have two independent variables with three levels and one dependent variable.

Thanks in advance!

Dave

Comment: Ordinal regression with the two IVs as factors.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional choice for this situation is a two-way ANOVA. Whether that really makes sense to do in your situation depends on the many things about your study that you haven't mentioned (what the variables represent, how much data you have, what the goal of your analysis is, etc.).